# How can I have a persistent view in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

We are using a UInavigationController with one of the views being one that plays soundtracks.

We are using the AVfountation framework.

We navigate to audiolist(where music is played) on button click

```
-(IBAction)audioBtnClicked
{
    audiolist *audio=[[audiolist alloc] initWithNibName:@"audiolist" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewContrller:audio animated:YES];
    [audiolist release];
}
```

When the user plays music and navigates away, the music continues playing

**Problem:** when the user navigates back to the list of songs and plays another track,
2 songs are playing at the same time.

We think that a new instance of `audiolist` is created everytime the user navigates back.
We would like to only have one instance of `audiolist`. How do we make the first instance of `audiolist` persistent and how do we refer back to it?

Comment: xcode is just an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
[audio release];
```

and not

```
[audiolist release];
```

audiolist seems to be your class name. The naming conventions says that classes should be capital and camel-cased, so it should be AudioList. It'll make your code more readable.

To have one single shared instance of your AudioList, you could do this:

Add a class method to your header:

```
+ (AudioList *) sharedInstance;
```

then add  this to your implementation file:

```
@implementation AudioList

static AudioList *gSharedInstance = nil;

+ (AudioList *) sharedInstance {
    if (gSharedInstance == nil) {
        gSharedInstance = [[AudioList alloc] init];
    }

    return gSharedInstance;
}
```

Now you can always access that instance with

```
[AudioList sharedInstance];
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. This implementation works well and fixed the issue we were having.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, David. Please accept and upvote my answer in case it was helpful to you :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi Johannes, I've accepted it but unfortunately not able to upvote it as I'm a fairly new user. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton AudioManager class that handles all your music playback. When you navigate to that view controller, grab the shared instance of that AudioManager to do whatever you do in that view.

You don't want the view to persist as that would be bad separation of MVC.

Apple has some discussion of different design patterns and their objective-c implementations, including the singleton:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6

Comment: Thanks for introducing singleton! I have tried to use it for a different problem but am facing issues now as well. Since it is a different issue altogether I started a new question thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783741/singleton-causes-app-to-crash-when-changing-view-controllers