# Singleton causes app to crash when changing View Controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, singleton

I am trying to use a singleton class to choose custom content to display based on the selection made by the user. It goes like this: a list is displayed, users select one of the rows in the list, and the app goes into another ViewController view. The ViewController used is the same for all the list options, however the content is different. Currently I managed to do this for only 1 option, and am trying to use a singleton class to tell the app which content to choose from.

This is what happens when the option "Raffles Landing Site" is chosen:

```
if(landmarkSelected== @"Raffles Landing Site") {
    RafflesLandmarkInfo *rafflesLandmarkInfo = [[RafflesLandmarkInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"RafflesLandmarkInfo" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rafflesLandmarkInfo animated:YES];
    [rafflesLandmarkInfo release];
```

This opens a UIWebView implemented as follows:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"raffles" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

I created a singleton class as described here: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

I added an NSMutableString property to it and changed the previous codes to the following:

```
if(landmarkSelected== @"Raffles Landing Site") {
        LandmarkController* instance = [LandmarkController sharedInstance];
        [instance.activeLandmark setString:@"raffles"];
        RafflesLandmarkInfo *rafflesLandmarkInfo = [[RafflesLandmarkInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"RafflesLandmarkInfo" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rafflesLandmarkInfo animated:YES];
        [rafflesLandmarkInfo release];
```

and

```
 if (instance.activeLandmark ==@"raffles"){
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:instance.activeLandmark ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

but the app crashes when I select Raffles Landing Site from the list of options. The culprit seems to be

```
[instance.activeLandmark setString:@"raffles"];
```

How do I set the activeLandmark string in the first ViewController so when it loads the second ViewController it displays content based on the value set in the first ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

In your singleton, is the activeLandmark string being alloced/initialized before you try and assign to it?

Comment: It is done like this in the singleton LandmarkController.m file

`code`
- (id)init {
 if (self = [super init]){
  activeLandmark = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
 }
}

Comment: What are the property modifiers on activeLandmark?  I'd probably just use a NSString myself instead of an NSMutableString.

Comment: Hi Tom. What is meant by property modifiers? I'm fairly new to iOS coding and am working on a really tight schedule for a school coding project which doesn't allow sufficient time to learn to do things the right way, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge. I used NSMutableString to be able to use setString to change the value of activeLandmark. I have looked at the NSString documentation and am not sure how to do that with NSString.

Comment: *not sure how to do that with NSString* -- `instance.activeLandmark = @"raffles";`

Comment: (But of course that has nothing to do with the problem.  It's axiomatic that singleton implementations will be screwed up, so that's probably the source of your troubles.)

Comment: Wow, thanks Daniel. I have no need for NSMutableString then. May I ask, if singleton implementations will always be screwed up, then why do people implement them? More importantly, how would you suggest an alternative implementation for the problem here?